# Nginx listen to and forward all ports to locahost

Tags: nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have set up Nginx for SSL certificate. What do I need to do now to forward all external requests from `https://example.com:<port>` to `localhost:<port>`?

Eg. HTTP queries to https://example.com:3000 should be forwarded to a local NodeJS server listening on localhost:3000, and https://example.com:3001 should be forwarded to localhost:3001, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-reverse-proxy) could helps you redirect URLS and ports

For example : Below configuration block redirects request from http://example.com:3000 to 127.0.0.1:3000

```
upstream app_nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  }

upstream web_nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  }
server {
   listen 3000 default ssl;
   listen   [::]:3000;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate    /root/certs/app.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key    /root/certs/app.key;   

  server_name example.com;

  if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass https://app_nodejs;
  proxy_redirect off;
}

}
server {
  listen 3001 default ssl;
  listen   [::]:3001;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate    /root/certs/web.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /root/certs/web.key;       

  server_name example.com;

 if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
   rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_pass https://web_nodejs;
  proxy_redirect off;
 }

 }
```

Comment: It's giving an error that port 3000 is in use (by my NodeJS app), so it seems like the reverse proxy is not working correctly.

Comment: seems like the nginx listening port and the nodejs app cannot be run on the same port.